# what does "more important skills" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Team or group activities can teach more important skills for life than those done alone.

Does "more important skills" here mean skills that are more important or more skills that are important? why?

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from the statement- "Team or group activities can teach more important skills for life than those done alone." : the statement compares the learning's received while doing a team/group activity to an activity done alone. With that idea in mind the statement seems to be pointing towards a meaning of - 'more skills that are important'.

Comment: thanks. if no context was given, is the meaning of this phrase ambiguous? are there any expressions to avoid the confusion?